# Powershell Copy-Item - Access Denied

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I'm writing a script that will open files in a directory and perform a find/replace.  But before I do that I would like to make copies of the files in the same directory as the original file.  All files exist in the C:\Program Files (x86) directory.  The script errors out stating that access to the directory is denied.  I see that Copy-Item has a -Credential parameter, but on my test machine I don't have any local Administrator permissions.  Doesn't seem like there is going to be any way to copy the file to the same directory.  Can I specify the system's temp folder (Windows 7 Professional) and just write it there?  I'd like to find a way to copy the file to the same directory as the source file, however.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Vista and above default to not allowing non-administrative users to write to the `%PROGRAMFILES% folder. This means that you're not going to be allowed to copy the files there; you're also not going to be able to save them after doing your find/replace operation.

You can write them to your user documents folder (`%USERPROFILE%\Documents`) folder instead, if that will work for you.