# Access is denied - confusion over COPY-ITEM

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to copy some files from my server to a workstation. If I change `$Foldername` to `C:\`the process works fine. However if I leave the code the way it is, i.e. If I decide to copy files to `C:\Program Files\Interrogator`.

I get this error:

```
Copy-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Interrogator\Setup Instructions.txt' is denied.
At C:\Users\coduy\Desktop\Copy2Test.ps1:20 char:10
+ Copy-Item <<<<  -Path \\10.10.0.10\DeploymentShare\Applications\JDE-Interrogator\* -Destination $Foldername
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\10.10.0.10\De...nstructions.txt:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], Unauthorized
   AccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I can see that the access is denied but why? I have not shared any of the folders and that should not make any difference if I decide to copy to `C:\` or `C:\Program Files`

```
 $net = New-Object -comobject Wscript.Network
    $net.MapNetworkDrive("Z:","\\10.13.0.10\DeploymentShare\Applications\JDE Interrogator",0,"mydomain\coduy","P0kroy$")

    $uncServer = "\\10.10.0.10\"
    $uncFullPath = "\\10.13.0.10\DeploymentShare\Applications\JDE Interrogator"
    $username = "coduy"
    $password = "password"
    $Foldername="C:\Program Files\Interrogator"


    net use $uncServer $password /USER:$username
    try
    {

    mkdir C:\'Program Files'\Interrogator
    Copy-Item -Path \\10.10.0.10\DeploymentShare\Applications\JDE-Interrogator\* -Destination $Foldername


    }
    finally {
    net use $uncServer /delete
    }
```

Comment: Does that file already exist at the destination, and if it does is it read-only, and do you have rights to modify the file?

Comment: This is an issue with permissions and is more suitable for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: How do you move it to other pages?

Comment: @user1317553, close this question and open a new one on SU or SF. Since you found a an answer please accept it as a solution so the question can be closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell Copy-Item - Access Denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008924/powershell-copy-item-access-denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that other user has similar issue and this seems to be a reasonable answer:

> Windows Vista and above default to not allowing non-administrative
>   users to write to the `%PROGRAMFILES% folder. This means that you're
>   not going to be allowed to copy the files there; you're also not going
>   to be able to save them after doing your find/replace operation.
>
> You can write them to your user documents folder
>   (%USERPROFILE%\Documents) folder instead, if that will work for you.
>
> share|edit answered Dec 23 '12 at 6:32
>
> Ken White
>   74.5k770140